# Onclick não funciona no Firefox e IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esta função não funciona no firefox e no IE:

No javascript:

```
function scrollTo() {
   var _offset = 90;
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#videoItem').offset().top - _offset }, 'slow');
   return false;
 }
```

No HTML:

```
<div class="videoItem"  onclick="javascript:scrollTo();"></div>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Mude o nome da função, esso nome é de outro metodo nativo de JS. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp. E veja se resulta

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! Só que no Chrome a tela dá uma piscada, sabe me dizer porque?

Comment: Acho que pode ser algum callback, verifica que outras funções está sendo executado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você nomeou a função com o mesmo nome que uma função nativa do Javascript. Renomeie a função que passará a funcionar. [Veja](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) o site da MDN